# Прогнозирование временных рядов

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Мы пошли на хакатон для опыта, но у нас немного возникли затруднения.

Вот два файла (само задание и данные к нему):

- [яндекс диск](https://yadi.sk/d/lIEvEC09NgPKmg)
- [гугл диск](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xLmhAak0VyutEK5CPeUPmS0nsD7nHXts)

В нашем распоряжении данные о внесении и снятии банковских средств. При этом есть даты, все по датам. Также у нас есть данные о том, когда привозят средства сотрудники банка .

Задача состоит в том,чтобы создать такую программу. Как я понял, реализуется это машинным обучением, которая будет это дело анализировать и выдавать нам график, когда нужно подвозить средства.

Подскажите идею, мы совсем не шарим. Просто направьте нас, даже это не плохо было бы.

Немного о том, что мы сами придумали:

Мы подумали над тем, что мы можем анализировать снятие средств, вывести среднее значение и также самое большое. И на основе этого анализа сделать прогноз на то, когда, по мере истощения средств, нужно привозить еще .

Ну, как-то так, буду рад, если кто-то чем-либо поможет.

Comment: Направляю - тема называется «прогнозирование временных рядов». Удачи!